# Obtain asyncronous result from listener

Tags: scala, concurrency, locks

Imagaine I have a the following code:

```
class Listener {

  //excuted by thread 1
  //called when request is finshed
  def complete(result: Result) = //get result as return value for request

}


//excuted by thread 2
def request: Result = {
  //Do something that invokes Listener.complete
  //return result from listener
}
```

As I've already written in the comments I want to get the result of my Listener.complete function as result for my request function. I could archive that by combining a lock with a var but that isn't good scala style. So what are the alernatives ?

Comment: Look at  akka actors or if you want inbuilt solution then use Futures(http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Comment: The Listener is provided so I have to use it and can't use akka or Futures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def request: Future[Result] = {
  val p = promise[Result]

  new Listener {
    def complete(result: Result) = p.success(result)
  }

  p.future
}
```

Now you have a `Future[Result]` you can pass back to your caller.  If you have an asynchronous function (which you do) you shouldn't try to hide that fact.  Instead, use a future and let your caller work with that, using `map`, `flatMap`, `onSuccess`, etc.

Comment: exactly what I want! tanks